# Publicando no Azure - FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\myapp.xml'

Tags: asp.net-web-api, microsoft-azure, asp.net-core, swagger

Estou tentando publicar uma aplicação ASP.NET Core Web Api para um recurso Api App do Azure.

Esse erro começou a aparecer após eu marcar a opção "Remove additional files at destination":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E depois disso, comecei a receber o erro e não consegui mais fazer funcionar.

Esse erro ocorre quando o app tenta achar o arquivo .XML para o Swagger. Eu tenho o seguinte código para isso:

```
// Determine base path for the application.
var basePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;

// Complete path
var xmlPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "myapp.xml");

// Set the comments path for the swagger json and ui.
options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
```

E essas são as configurações do projeto para a documentação XML:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Funciona perfeitamente rodando local na minha máquina.

Alguma ideia, por favor?

Comment: Marcar o checkbox novamente (?)

Comment: @LINQ parece óbvio, mas não funciona haha

Comment: Putz. Mas o arquivo tá sendo enviado? Não tá dando erro na publicação?

Comment: O arquivo está sendo enviado e não há erro na hora do publish. Tudo 100%. Já alterei o caminho onde o .XML é gerado, já coloquei para "copiar sempre" e nada feito. Já deletei o recurso do Azure e adicionei de novo e o erro persiste. Bizarro.

Answer (score 1):

Já faz muito tempo e não teve resposta aqui, porém segue minha solução:

Resolvi esse problema colocando o **output correto** nas propriedades do projeto, principalmente no modo **Release**, e depois publicando novamente no Azure.

[image: Release]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]